# A view that looks like a mapview with icons but is actually a background picture

Tags: android, view, background, android-mapview

I would like to have a container with icons that exceeds the device size so that the user can drag the screen to see the unseen icons and can click on the icons to perform further actions. This should be similar in the experience to the MapView but I don't really need a map just a  background picture of my own. What is the best view to implement this?

Thanks,
  Simon

Comment: I would start with a RelativeView inside a ScrollView. You may want to take a look at [Google Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Comment: static maps require URL and keys. Can I implement them just with my local image and without acquiring keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this project https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap

It should be what you need.